# JS how to save contentWindow as PDF (blob)?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, blob

I have an iframe. I need to save PDF that it's showing as variable (blob). iframe.contentWindow.print() works fine but I don't need to print pdf, just save it. Is it possible?